# download files with powershell, powershell version of wget

Tags: powershell, wget

I am one of the few that decided to learn powershell instead of bash. I'd like to learn how to do the same thing as wget, for powershell. How to I do the following commands in powershell.

```
wget -r --no-parent http://curric.rithmschool.com/springboard/exercises/
wget -r --no-parent http://curric.rithmschool.com/springboard/slides/
wget -r --no-parent http://curric.rithmschool.com/springboard/lectures/
```

Comment: the most obvious is to install the windows version of `wget` and call that from inside PoSh. [*grin*] ///// for pure powershell, take a look at `Invoke-RestMethod`. the ps7+ version of that cmdlet is supposed to be quite a bit better than the ps5.1 version.

Comment: To be clear, this is not a difference bash vs posh but Unix vs Windows. wget is a _program_, not part of bash. Most Unix systems come with wget, and you can run it from _any_ shell or even without a shell. Windows systems don't come with wget, and even if you install bash on Windows (you can) that doesn't give you wget; OTOH if you install wget you can run it from anywhere. Of course some things, notably WSL, provide a whole range of tools, typically including _both_ bash and wget.

Comment: alternatively you could install powershell on linux, :)

Comment: So, this is a webpage of links to other webpages. I was told it was a file. So it seems this command was trying to download the page for offline use... Not sure if this is helpful. I appreciate everyone's fast responses.

Comment: [3 ways to download files with PowerShell](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

See here for 4 ways to interact with a webserver depending on the nature of the service you are accessing and the way you want to access them: https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-download-file/

I'd recommend the System.Net.WebClient approach if you just want to download a file, but there are variants for API calls and other protocols like BITS.

This is is a call I saw in a script I was working with earlier today that will just download a file (a CI/CD agent for azure):

```
$WebClient=New-Object Net.WebClient; 
$Uri='https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.181.1/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.181.1.zip';
$WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, "c:\path\to\download\to\agent.zip");
```

Comment: `Get-WebRequest` and `Invoke-WebRequest` too.

Comment: But `wget -r` doesn't download ONE page; it follows references and links and automatically downloads ALL accessible URLs, or at least MANY depeding on the other arguments like `--no-parent` in this Q. That's the difficult part.